# Entity Framework select parents and N number of children

Tags: entity-framework-4

Simply put, how can I do something like:

Select all `Departments` together with **2 of its latest** `Staff`.

I don't need all staff loaded, just 2.

Note: I need lazyloading enabled so that staffdetails is still accessible if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF doesn't allow filtering / ordering or limiting number of returned records on navigation property in eager loading.  You must use projection to anonymous type or custom type:

```
var data = from d in context.Departments
           select new 
              {
                  Department = d,
                  Staffs = d.Staff.OrderBy(...).Take(2)
              };
```

Comment: Not necessarily if you access staff only though the property in the new returned type.